# iOS local notifications disabled automatically if app isn't opened

Tags: ios, notifications

As I see in many apps when setting user notifications as reminders, it works fine but after a while when the user starts to ignore opening the notification or the app it won't send any more notifications.
Is there a way to disable this behavior and continue sending the notifications even if they don't open the app?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you mean. I have never experienced the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: I have a health app which I would not mention here so it's not considered as advertising but it has a feature to set alert to drink water each 2 hours but after a few days of non-activity "no app opening or cancelling the notification" it would stop sending the notifications.

Comment: "Many apps" so mention a different one. If you are using an app as an example to show a problem then use it. It makes it infinitely easier to understand your problem if we can see it in action.

Comment: A game like shadow fight https://itunes.apple.com/eg/app/shadow-fight-2/id696565994?mt=8 or clash of clans you will see this happening after ignoring notifications and not opening the game for some time. Duolingo is an another example "it would be disabled after 3 days or so"

Comment: See my answer. I imagine these are not using recurring notifications due to their limitations but are using multiple one time notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing sounds like local notifications. These are scheduled in code to go off at a specific time. As far as I know there is no such thing as a recurring local notification. They are "simulated" by creating many single local notifications to begin with.

**Edit**
As PaulW pointed out. Recurring notifications are possible but are rarely used due to their limitations.

When the app is opened it runs some code to create some more local notifications.

If the app is not opened then the code never runs to create the additional notifications.

So, in this example, it is not iOS stopping the recurring notifications because you haven't opened the app. The notifications stop recurring because you don't open the app and give it the opportunity to create more of them.

So, to answer your question. No. The only way to delay this as long as possible is to create notifications that cover a long time into the future. But then I believe there is a limit to the number of scheduled notifications. (A quick google comes up with a limit of 64 scheduled notifications per app).

**Edit** you could also use repeating notifications but they are limited to repeat every one unit of time. Once a day, once and hour, once a minute, etc... so you can't do it every two hours.

Alternatively you could use a backend to send remote notifications. These could theoretically recur infinitely because the app is not required to create them. Of course, this assumes you have the infrastructure setup to develop this.

Comment: You can create recurring local notifications, but they aren't very flexible; e.g. You can have once per day or once per hour but not "once every two hours between 9 and 5", so most apps use the approach you describe.

Comment: @Paulw11 ah ok. I assume in the example given that the app has done my method then. There is nothing documented about repeating notifications being cancelled by the OS.

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is the correct explanation since that is the most common technique due to the limitations of repeating notifications

Comment: @Paulw11 can't they be overridden to be every 2 hours or whatever the interval we need to use?

Comment: @XIII no. Look at the documentation for UILocalNotification. The only option when setting it repeated is the repeating time calendar unit. So, Minute, Hour, Day, Week, Month, etc... there isn't an option for 2 hours etc...

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister I will check it and see